How many triangles in the picture?
A colleague suggested counting how many triangles there are. Where lines cross they are concurrent.


Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!

As it's a puzzle stack exchange, all the maths isn't shown, but there is a formula for the pattern of side of length $n$, in the diagram $n=8$
$$\frac{n}{12}(13n^2+15n+20)$$
for $n/2$ even and the same formula but $-1$ if $n/2$ is odd
for anyone who wants the proof...
It'll be long, so here's a photo of some working for n=16, the bottom page is a summary of results for the even numbers 2-20

Partial proof and a way to get to a formula.
First page, top left, how many of these triangles  /\ first column, smallest, horizontal edge along bottom, then smallest horizontal edge next row up etc...next column how many similar but one size bigger on bottom, then next row up etc...until biggest of these type, column 9 bottom, next row up etc...
First page top right diagram to help explanation, green added later, shows n=8 although the rest of first page is about n=16
bottom half of first page getting to a result for n=16, T stands for triangle numbers e.g. T(7) = 0.5*(7)(7+1)
Second half of formula is for triangles this shape |_ with diagonal length 2 at first like BE, but all positions, derived in a similar way to other shape triangles, (all details not shown)
First bit of formula for the smallest possible triangles, the 4 is for rotations.
Then a list of results 2-20 is
16, 96, 288, 648, 1224, 2072, 3240, 4784, 6752, 9200
with differences being about the same on the third row, so cubic,
56,48,56,48,56 so 2 sets etc... 16,288,1224, difference on 3rd row of 416 so divided by 6 = $\frac{208}{3}n^3$, later replace term number with $\frac{n}{4}$ and simplify, goes to $\frac{13}{12}n^3$ etc....   Hope it makes sense

Please consider including a mathematical proof for the formula.

@FirstName LastName  a partial proof has been added

A small program counting the triangles confirms $count = (13 n^3 + 15 n^2 + 20 n) / 12$ for n a multiple of 4 and the same -1 for n = 2 (mod 4).

Thankyou  @FlorianF   it's now also been proved mathematically, but it's the puzzle stack exchange, so it won't be posted.  these things can take many hours to get neat and post, sorry, but will have to leave this one!

And fwiw for $n$ odd I find $count = (13 n^3 + 15 n^2 - n - 3 )/12$.

@FlorianF seems right, maybe all that's left is to find a formula for rectangular grids.  lengths $a$ and $b$.  Formula must revert to those above for $a$=$b$, might interest the maths stack exchange community

It's been posted as a question on Mathematics Stack Exchange here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4991081/how-many-triangles-in-the-picture

I am considering the idealized version of this image—as hexomino pointed out in their comment and was confirmed by OP.
Diagonal Approach
The first observation is that

every triangle needs exactly one or exactly two diagonal lines in order to be formed.

To begin,

the first class of triangles(exactly one diagonal) is easily seen to be symmetric in respect to the diagonal piece forming it, leading to exactly as many triangles above as below.
Every diagonal forms exactly $(N-1)+(N-2)...+1$ triangles, with $N$ being the number of horizontal lines it touches.
There are 14 diagonals in the image, with 4 touching 3, 4 touching 5, 4 touching 7 and 2 touching 9 horizontal lines.
Half of these are leaning left, the other half are leaning right, making them symmetric as well.
The shortest lines touch 3 horizontal lines, forming 3 triangles below,
the second shortest lines touch 5 horizontal lines, forming 10 triangles below,
the third shortest lines touch 7 horizontal lines, forming 21 triangles below,
the longest line touches 9 horizontal lines, forming 36 triangles below.

This leads to…

\[4\times(2\times3+2\times10+2\times21+36)=416\] triangles of the first class.

Now,

the second class (exactly two diagonals) is also easily seen to be symmetric over the image—consider only the "left-facing" triangles: there are exactly as many up, down and right facing triangles due to the double symmetry.
I don't have a nice algorithm for these, but they are easy to count.
Class 2, left-facing with a size of one horizontal line has exactly $28(16 + 12)$ triangles,
class 2, left-facing with a size of two horizontal lines has exactly $18 (12 + 6)$ triangles,
class 2, left-facing with a size of three horizontal lines has exactly $9 (6 + 3)$ triangles,
class 2, left-facing with a size of four horizontal lines has exactly 3 triangles
and there are no larger class 2 triangles.

This leads us to…

\[4\times(28+18+9+3) = 232\] class 2 triangles.

In sum,

I have thus counted 648 triangles in the idealized image.

Vertex Approach
As requested, here is another approach, focusing on vertices instead of diagonals.

Every triangle in the image is isosceles and has a right angle.
Consider only the vertex that contains the right angle.
Again, we have two classes of triangles:
Class 1, where the right angle is formed between two orthogonal (i.e. non-diagonal) lines and
Class 2, where the right angle is formed between two diagonal lines.
These two classes each have the same members as the classes in the first approach.

Class 1

 now has a double symmetry - each vertex that forms one such triangle (red) has three symmetric partners that do the same (blue):

 This means we only need to consider one of these cases - I am considering only triangles that are in the first quadrant in respect to the vertex (red).
 Each of the triangles ends in one diagonal and has unit sizes for their orthogonal lines.
 This leads us to the possibility of only considering the large right triangle below the diagonals for possible target triangles - marked in blue, red and yellow for three of the diagonals.

 Now, count the number of vertices inside the colored areas, but not on the diagonal. All of these form a valid and unique triangle.
 Their number is $A^2/2 + A/2$ for A being the number of line segments on each side of the large triangle. These are also called triangle numbers.
 The large triangles are symmetric as well and, starting from the largest diagonal in the middle, that has N (in this case N = 8) line segments, have $N-2n$ line segments.
 We can cheat a little with Gaussian rounding to reach a machine calculable representation of the diagonal lengths:
 $⌊n/2⌋\times2$

  This means, we have a formula that is only dependent on the number of line segments of the large square:

$X1 = 4\times \Sigma(A^2/2 + A/2)|A=⌊n/2⌋\times2|n=\{0..8\}$
$= 4\times \Sigma(A^2/2 + A/2|A=\{0,0,2,2,4,4,6,6,8\})$
$= 4\times(0 + 0 + 3 + 3 + 10 + 10 + 21 + 21 + 36) = 416$

Class 2

 also has a double symmetry - each vertex that forms one such triangle (red) has three symmetric partners that do the same (blue):

 So again, we also only need to consider one of these cases.
 Here, we have very limited vertices (16+12 = 28) that can even form these triangles. Observe also, that from the outside to the inside, each class of vertices forms one more triangle with red vertices forming one, blue vortices forming two, orange vortices forming three and finally yellow vortices forming four triangles.

 Since these triangles are twice as high as they are wide, each consecutive step reduces the number of vertical vertices by two, but the number of horizontal vortices by one.
 Initially, we have $N/2\times N/2 + N/2\times(N/2 - 1)$ vertices.
 We can cheat with Gaussian rounding to reach a machine calculable representation of the number of vertices again - this is a little ugly but may be possible to improve:
$max(0,(N/2-⌊n\times0.5⌋)\times(N/2-2\times⌊n\times0.5⌋)+(N/2-⌊(n-1)\times0.5⌋)\times(N/2-1-2\times⌊(n-1)\times0.5⌋)) $
 Here N is the number of line segments, n is the number of vertices produced by the vertex and limited to $N/2$ because of the height of these triangles.

 So, we have a formula again that is only dependent on the number of line segments of the large square:

$X2 = 4\times\Sigma(max(0,(8/2-⌊n\times0.5⌋)\times(8/2-2\times⌊n\times0.5⌋)+(8/2-⌊(n-1⌋\times0.5))\times(8/2-1-2\times⌊(n-1)\times0.5⌋))|n={1,2,3,4})$
$= 4\times(max(0,16+12)+max(0,6+12)+max(0,6+3)+max(0,0+3))$
$= 4\times(28+18+9+3) = 232  $


 Again, we reach $416+232=648$ for the total number of triangles on a square image with side length of 8. This description is now generalized to $N\times N$, too - I suspect NxM would need a few adjustments but should also be feasible.


I have another argumentation (focusing on vertices that contain the right angle of the triangle) that should lead to the same result and may be easier to follow (and possibly easier to generalize to NxM). I can add that to this answer if you wish.

Yes, please.  Add that.

Even another general argument case NxN with N=2^n would already be an enlightening extra. Say, some compact, iterative or recursive, formula that works for 2x2 and 4x4 and beyond.

@ZamirBezgoev I have added the vertex approach - that one also contains a mathematical description and is generalized to NxN (at least for even N, unsure about uneven).


By "diagonal direction" I mean bottom-left to top-right or top-left to bottom-right.

By "longitudinal direction" I mean horizontal or vertical.

Preliminary analysis

Every diagonal segment (D-seg) uniquely induces 2 triangles.

Every even-length longitudinal segment (E-seg) uniquely induces 2 triangles, unless one of the triangles goes off the board, in which case it uniquely induces 1 triangle.

On counting sub-segments

"-"     1 of length 1
"--"    1 of length 2 + 2 of length 1
"---"   1 + 2 + 3
"----"  1 + 2 + 3 + 4
etc.


So (barred any constraints), for any segment of length L, the number of sub-segments is:

1 + 2 + ... + L = 1/2*L*(L+1)

Counting over D-segs

Parallel to each diagonal direction, there are 7 diagonals of lengths resp. 2, 4, 6, 8, 4, 6, 2.


The corresponding sequence of sub-segment counts is 3, 10, 21, 36, 21, 10, 3, for a sum total of 104 D-segs.


Since there are 2 diagonal directions times 2 induced triangles per segment, the total number of triangles induced by the D-segs is 104*2*2 = 416.

Counting over E-segs

Let's index longitudinals from 0 (left or top) to 8 (right or bottom):


Parallel to each longitudinal direction, there are 9 longitudinals whose usable lengths are 8 or 6 for even-indexed vs odd-indexed longitudinals resp., and we need to take into account edge cases.


Let's just consider each case:




the longitudinal 4 (at the center) induces triangles




on both sides
for every contained E-seg
over a length of 8;






the longitudinals 3 and 5 induce triangles




on both sides
for every contained E-seg
over a length of 6;






the longitudinals 2 and 6 induce triangles




on one side (internal)
for every contained E-seg
over a length of 8;




on the other side (external)
for every contained E-seg of length <= 4
over a length of 8;






the longitudinals 1 and 7 induce triangles




on one side (internal)
for every contained E-seg
over a length of 6;




on the other side (external)
for every contained E-seg of length <= 2
over a length of 6;






the longitudinals 0 and 8 induce triangles




on one side (internal)
for every contained E-seg
over a length of 8;






Only over even-length sub-segments, the sub-segment counts for each case are:




longitudinal 4 => 40 triangles:




1+2+3+8/2 = 10 E-segs times 2 sides times 2 directions
for a total of 10*2*2 = 40 triangles;






longitudinals 3 and 5 => 24*2 = 48 triangles:




1+2+6/2 = 6 E-segs times 2 sides times 2 directions
for a total of 6*2*2 = 24 triangles;






longitudinals 2 and 6 => (20+14 = 34)*2 = 68 triangles:




1+2+3+8/2 = 10 E-segs times 2 directions
for a total of 10*2 = 20 triangles;




0+0+3+8/2 = 7 E-segs times 2 directions
for a total of 7*2 = 14 triangles;






longitudinals 1 and 7 => (12+6 = 18)*2 = 36 triangles:




1+2+6/2 = 6 E-segs times 2 directions
for a total of 6*2 = 12 triangles;




0+0+6/2 = 3 E-segs times 2 directions
for a total of 3*2 = 6 triangles;






longitudinals 0 and 8 => 20*2 = 40 triangles:




1+2+3+8/2 = 10 E-segs times 2 directions
for a total of 10*2 = 20 triangles;






Whence the total number of triangles induced by the E-segs is 40+48+68+36+40 = 232.

Counting total

Summing up, the total number of induced triangles is 416+232 = 648.

[Kudos to  Jaap Scherphuis for pointing out my initial mistakes.]

For some E-segs, the larger triangles will only fit on one side, so you are overcounting there. Your trick of collapsing opposite edges together is only valid or size 1 triangles. For example, only the length 8 E-segments in the centre of the board support such large triangles on both sides. Note also that some lines don't have a valid length 8 E-segment at all since the diagonals don't meet the end points.

@JaapScherphuis  Ah, right on both accounts...  I will try and fix it.  Thank you.

@JaapScherphuis  Fixed, I would think, especially since my result matches Brian404's. :)  I have mentioned you in the answer, hoping it's OK.
